# How to Turn of Entity Framework Code First Pluralization Per Table

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am supporting a Legacy .Net Entity Framework application.
This app makes uses of Pluralization for the table names.

I am introducing a new data item/table name "Media".

However, Entity Framework is incorrectly pluralizing this to "Medias".

How can I turn off pluralization on a per-table basis?

I've done a bit of research so far, but the only material I've found refers to turning pluralization on and off for the entire data set. This is not possible for supporting the legacy application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the table name in the mapping. If you use fluent interface you can use ToTable("Media"), if you use DataAnnotation you can specify [Table("Media")] before the class.